# How to re-enable drive based sharing? (\\hostname\e$)

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

I have a drive on a remote machine that I want to share at the root (E:) so that I can just connect via the run prompt using `\\<hostname>\e$\`, however, when I share the drive with “Everyone” and try Read and Read/Write access and try to connect from my workstation I get the “Enter network credential” prompt. Previously the drive was shared and this wasn't an issue but a while back I turned off sharing while troubleshooting an issue and now need to re-enable it.

How do you properly share a drive without requiring the network credential prompt for everyone? A quick google returned “add guest account to share” which didn't work and the other alternative is to disable password protection on the client which isn't desirable. The server is 2008 R2 Standard.

Comment: If you're giving 'Everyone' permission to E$, make sure 'Everyone' also has permission to the actual E: folder.   Alternately you could mount the drive locally with credentials to a user with access on the server?  `net use Z: \\HOSTNAME\E$ /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME PASSWORD`

Comment: I don't want to have to go to my bosses machine and map the drive, it's worked before without having to do that junk by just going into the run prompt and type "\\server\e$\.

Comment: Just as an FYI: you shouldn't be doing this anyway.  The drive root share is known as the administrative share... and is not something you want everyone to be able to access without a credential prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the administrator of the remote machine or your username and password is the same as the administrator of the local machine, you will connect to the e$ share without prompts.